# Liquibase Snowflake integration - specifically: generateChangeLog

Tags: liquibase, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When invoking:mvn liquibase:generateChangeLog I get this error:

```
*Object 'DATAWAREHOUSE_DB_DEV.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINTS' does not exist or not authorized.*
```

Has anyone found a workaround for this issue? It seems Snowflake has a view DATAWAREHOUSE_DB_DEV.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS but Snowflake does not support synonyms and you can't create any new views in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA (to match what liquibase is looking for).

Comment: What version of Liquibase and the snowflake extension are you using?

Comment: I'm using the latest plugin:
<groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
<artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.8.6</version>

I'm not using the snowflake extension. The basic mvn liquibase:update command seems to be working correctly. Only the generateChangeLog is not.

Comment: The best way to approach this would be to use the Liquibase Snowflake extension. In general, unless a new database platform works almost exactly like an existing platform, some customization will need to be done. There is a snowflake extension for Liquibase that you should try out. See https://liquibase.jira.com/wiki/spaces/CONTRIB/pages/113372651/Snowflake+extension

Answer (score 2):

This seems to me like a Liquibase version issue or something similar.

If you do need a workaround, can you create a view in a different schema that would work with your solution?

Akin to this:

```
create view public.constraints(constraint_catalog, constraint_schema, constraint_name) as (
      -- Start at the top of the hierarchy ...
      select constraint_catalog, constraint_schema, constraint_name
        from information_schema.table_constraints
  );

select * from public.constraints;
```

Comment: That's what I'd like to do. I can create the view with no issues:
create view "DATAWAREHOUSE_DB_DEV"."PUBLIC"."CONSTRAINTS" as
select * from "DATAWAREHOUSE_DB_DEV"."INFORMATION_SCHEMA"."TABLE_CONSTRAINTS";
But is there a way to configure Liquibase to use this new view instead of the one it's trying to find?

Comment: Did you find a solution for that?